# emacs dired create a copy of image with 50% brightness

Tags: dired, images

I know in the command line in linux i can use image magick to quickly brighten an image

```
convert nebula.landscape.jpg -brightness-contrast 30 bright.jpg
```

im trying to create a function in emacs (dired?) to launch this command on an image and create a copy of that image (after the brightness command is run). I know one can use ! but i want it to be persistant over sessions and thus i thought of a function. The copy would have the .bright suffix added such as `image.bright.jpg`. can anyone help with an example.

if there are other internal emacs methods to do this i would be happy to use this as well. Also, if one couls save a list of commonly used commands used in ! and maybe use ivy/helm to choose them that also could work great.

Comment: Did you try **`!`** (`dired-do-shell-command`) followed by your command line?

Comment: thx drew. sorry i should have mentioned im looking for a funtion to do so. alternitavly, is there a way perhaps to bring up a list of user defined most used command for !? ill update the question

Comment: You can use a combination of `dired-get-file-for-visit`, `start-process`, `set-process-sentinel`.  Adding things like ivy/helm to your question breaks the tradition of one question per thread, and reduces the likelihood that an answer will be forthcoming for a variety of reasons.  I've written a few answers over the years that demonstrate how to launch function and/or new procesess after a previous process finishes successfully, and they are available by Googling things like:  **emacs start-process set-process-sentinel**

Comment: If you want your own, `dired-do-shell-command`-like command that runs only one dedicated command, then write a command that passes the shell command string to `dired-do-shell-command` (use `dired-get-marked-files` in the interactive spec - see the `dired-do-shell-command` code). If you want to associate given shell commands with given file-name patterns, customize option `dired-guess-shell-alist-user` (from `dired-x.el`).